# Why does the Maven site for my plugin not show the parameters from the base class?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I'm writing a Maven plugin, where some parameters are common to all Mojos. That's why I wrote an abstract base class containing them. This works well for the build, but when I create the Maven site for the plugin, the plugin documentation for the individual goals doesn't show those parameters.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug of the Maven site plugin?

**EDIT:**

I need to give some more details: We manage our data for configuration and I18N texts in XML files. At runtime, that data resides in a database. The purpose of the plugin is to check the XML (two goals), compare it to the database (two goals) and copy it to the database (two goals).

Since some parameters are required in all goals, I have abstract base classes that contain the Maven parameters.

Here's the hierarchy for the comparison goals:

```
AbstractMojo
+-- BaseReferenceDataMojo
    +-- BaseReferenceDatabaseMojo
        +-- BaseComparisonMojo
            +-- ConfigurationComparisonMojo
            +-- I18NComparisonMojo
```

So, for instance in `BaseReferenceDataManagerMojo`, I have the following Maven parameters:

```
public abstract class BaseReferenceDataManagerMojo extends AbstractMojo {
...

/**
 * The Maven project.
 */
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
protected MavenProject project;

/**
 * The start directory, where reference data files are search recursively.
 */
@Parameter(defaultValue = "src/main/resources", readonly = true, required = true, property = "startDirectory")
protected File startDirectory;

...
}
```

Way down in `ConfigurationComparisonMojo`, I have the following parameters:

```
@Mojo(name = "compare-configuration", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE, requiresProject = true)
public class ConfigurationComparisonMojo extends BaseComparisonMojo {
...

/**
 * The stage: Valid values are {@code development}, {@code integration}, {@code staging} and {@code production}.
 */
@Parameter(readonly = true, required = true, property = "stage")
private String stage;

...
}
```

As I wrote earlier, there's no problem configuring the `ConfigurationComparisonMojo` with, for instance, `startDirectory` - the base class parameters are injected correctly when the Mojo is called.

However, in the Maven site that I build using (amongst others) the `maven-plugin-plugin` (version 3.2), the documentation page for `reference-data-manager:compare-configuration` shows no parameters at all.

Comment: Show full pom file and some excerpts of your code? What is the purpose of your plugin?